# Mysql Workbench puts so many leading 0

Tags: mysql

I was gonna let this pass out since when getting the data from the database through python outputs normally(no leading zeroes), but then I had an error which says `Out of range value for column 'y1' at row 1`. First I am getting data from an API, what I initially thought was maybe the value really has leading zeroes, so I tried inserting my own data as you can see in the screenshot below, still turns out that it adds leading zeroes. Any suggestions on fixing this?

Table settings:

y1 to y4 and z1 to z4 data type : FLOAT

Collation: utf_unicode_c1

charset: utf8

[image: Too many leading zeroes]

Answer (score 0):

Change data type to decimal(18,2)

Answer (score 0):

Basically I have checked on the 'Zero Fill' that's why there are zeroes